# color does not fit the whole container

Tags: angular

I have this container I want to make it cover 100% the width and the height of the column but I don't understand why the color does not cover the whole column. in my code there is a white espace on the bottom of page and on the right side also .

this is the html code

```
<div class="row bigContainer">
  <div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-4 col-md-12 sideBarContainer">
    <side-bar></side-bar>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xl-10 col-lg-8 col-md-12overviewContainer">
  </div>
</div>
```

and this is the css :

```
.sideBarContainer {
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
}
.overviewContainer {
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
 // min-height: 100 vh;
  height: auto;

} 
.bigContainer{
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) document on how to ask a good question.

Comment: try: body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're experiencing with the white space at the bottom and right side of the page is likely due to the default margin and padding applied by the browser. Here's the updated CSS:

```
.sideBarContainer {
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
  height: 100%;
}

.overviewContainer {
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
  height: 100%;
}

.bigContainer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

This will make it so that there is no additional spacing added by default with margin: `0` and padding: `0`.